# I want to make some curves from 0 to 1 using iterations

Tags: curves, fractional-iteration

I want to make a few curves from 0 to 1 with a different growth acceleration.
So I tried this:

```
float y_mlt = 1/exp(-q/interations); // slow grow on the first stage but fast grow in second
float a=0.582;
float y_add=a/interations;

for (int x; x<interations; x++) {
    y = y*y_mlt + y_add;
}
```

y result is 1 - works

```
float y_mlt = exp(-q/(interations)); // non linear fast grow on the first stage but slow grow in second
float y_add=(q+a)/interations;

for (int x; x<interations; x++) {
    y = y*y_mlt + y_add;
}
```

y result is 1 - works

I find more curves for different values of **q** and **a**

- q=1 - - - - - - a=0.582
- q=2 - - - - - - a=0.313
- q=3 - - - - - - a=0.1559
- q=4 - - - - - - a=0.0743
- q=5 - - - - - - a=0.0335

The calculation of ***a*** was made by more trying, in a primitive way.

I want to generalize, so what it's the relation between ***q*** and ***a*** ?

iterations can have any int value, for 722 I get [graph of the curves using a=0.582](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFKwr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denoting $y$ on $k$-th iteration as $y_k$, `y_mlt` as $u$ and `y_add` as $v$, number of iterations as $N$, we have recurrent relation $y_{k + 1} = u \cdot y_k + v$, with initial conditions $y_0 = 0$ and require $y_N = 1$.

General solution of this relation is $y_n = c u^{n - 1} + v \frac{u^n - 1}{u - 1}$. $y_0 = 0$ gives $c = -uv$, so we have $y_n = v \cdot \frac{-u^{n + 1} + 2u^n - 1}{u - 1}$.

From this, $y_N = 1$ gives $v = \frac{u - 1}{-u^{N + 1} + 2u^N - 1}$.

Substituting $v = \frac{q + a}{N}$ and $u = \exp(-q / N)$, we get expression for $a$: $$a = N \cdot \frac{\exp(-q / N) - 1}{-\exp(-q / N)^{N + 1} + 2\exp(-q/N)^N - 1} - q$$

Comment: Your final equations are what I said in my post, but you cannot find out on a. I do not see the meaning, must find y_mlt and y_add according to a and q not reverse. But first it must be found a, independent of y_mlt and y_add.

Comment: The important part is previous, that expresses $u$ in terms of $v$ to satisfy $y_N = 1$. This allows us to express $a$ in terms of $q$ and $N$ (added explicit expression, though it's not nice on itself).

Comment: Great!  y_mlt = exp(-q/(interations)); y_add=(q+a)/interations; works great, the result it's perfect. But for y_mlt = 1/exp(-q/interations); float y_add=a/interations; it's not so perfect, also on q>5 is completely out of good result.

Comment: I think formula for the first example(my example) is different.

Comment: Yes, for the first case replace $q$ with $-q$ (it's the same as replacing $\exp(-q / N)$ with $1 / \exp(-q / N)$) and don't subtract $q$ in the end. Expression of `y_add` from `y_mlt` stays the same, then finding `a` from `q` depends on how ys are expressed.

Comment: Thanks works perfect!

Comment: exp(−q/N)N+1 the N+1 introduce same errors I think, iterations become iterations+1. I tested the formula in php